# Display a pin or something on Google glass compass

Tags: adt, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm exploring Google Glass Compass sample app, and trying to add a point or something on the compass like A blue dot which can be the position of a storm, something like that.

Is it possible or am I dreaming?

If possible, can someone show me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The Compass sample application already contains logic to do exactly this; see how [`CompassView`](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/glass/sample/compass/CompassView.java) can take a list of nearby `Place` objects that contain a geographical location and a name. The logic is there to compute the screen location where the pins should be drawn based on the relative bearing between the Glass user and the pin location.

The sample loads its pins from a JSON file in `res/raw/landmarks.json` and only shows those that are within 10 km of the user. You can test it out by editing this file to include a place near you, and then customize the drawing logic (and the distance filter) to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually want to display the position of something in degrees. Which part of the CompassView can I change? I know how to do that with Matrix (can rotate) . but displaying this on the gdk-compass looks tricky